# Search with * for redefine part of string

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

My question: I have a php search form in which I need the user to be able to redefine the search for only a part of the string.

Example (so far the user enter):

```
// Search Option

name: 20081111-1    //which means that the date of the item is 2008-11-11
```

Now, I would like the user to make a search which it will only include all the items in 2008 (desired user search):

```
// Search Option

 name: 2008*
```

How can I make this option in my search? Then I can search in my database for this part of the string only.

Thanks!

Comment: You say you want users to be able to search for _2008*_, fine. Are you stuck with how to write the php for it, the js or the sql?

Comment: how this got 3 upvotes?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You would take the PHP variable and replace the asterisk (*) with a percentage sign (%):

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name']; // remember to sanitize it
$name = str_replace('*', '%', $name);
?>
```

You would then create a MySQL query using your variable:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '$name'";
```

**Option 2:**

Use a MySQL date query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(column) = '2008'";
```

*Note that `column` should be a date or a datetime type.*

You should add contextual help for users or even dropdowns with possible options, so they don't search for '20081', for example.

Comment: Hi @ciprian. I am working on your solution. It seems to be working. I need to check it more deep! Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 4):

**Javascript**:

```
var str = '200811111-1';
var hasSubString = str.indexOf('2008') > -1;
var startsWithString = str.indexOf('2008') == 0;
```

**MySql**:

Has Substring 2008:

```
select * from table where col like '%2008%'
```

Starts with 2008:

```
select * from table where col like '2008%'
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case you can use in your query

```
date like '%2008-%'
```

instead of

```
date = '2008-11-11'
```

that means search for rows where date field contains the following pattern "2008-".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE pattern;
```

With this in sql you search using a pattern in your **case 2008**, you can use regular expression for do dynamically searching only numbers that start by 2.

Comment: Why nums that starts by 2?

Comment: is a year, only is he want to search only years, but you can do the regular to search to years of type 19xx and 2xxx